# react-router 3.10.10 IndexRoute

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I'm trying to figure out how to build apps with react and feathers.  I found Ben Awad's YouTube tutorial series (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=etq_vv_RVcU&index=2&list=PLN3n1USn4xlnulnnBGD2RMid_p7xVj9xU) and was following along with the code.  However I somehow got an issue he didn't cover.  When I go to run the code produced at the end of this video I get the following error:

```
./src/index.js
36:23-33 'react-router' does not contain an export named 'IndexRoute'.
```

Most of the stuff I've found seems to suggest that IndexRoute was phased out in v4, however running **npm -v react-route** returns 3.10.10 so I don't think it should be affected (could be wrong).  Does anyone have any thoughts about what might be causing this issue?  Thank you.

Comment: try to use version 2 of react router instead of 3, I think they remove `IndexRoute` from their code in further versions.

Comment: Is there a way to do that using the NPM tool (or will I need to do that manually), and will that mess up any of the other npm modules I currently have installed?

Comment: Found the npm command, npm install react-router@2

Comment: sorry, take to long to see your comment, Yes `react-router@2` refers into version 2 of your package. let me know what happened

Comment: Reverting worked.  Thanks!

Comment: so I post it as an answer :)

Answer (score 0):

I think `IndexRoute` was removed since version 2 from `react-route` so you must use version 2 of `react-route`, in order to do so you can install it using npm:

```
npm install --save react-router@2
```

Answer (score 0):

`IndexRoute` was removed in version `4` meaning that version `3.x` still has it. Install with npm:

```
npm install --save react-router@3.x
```

or

```
yarn add react-router@3.x
```